# search query using if or case statement

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I'm creating a Splunk Dashboard (using Dashboard Studio) that uses a dropdown to select which environment we want to look at. (PROD, UAT, or INT). The result is stored as a string in a variable called `$global_env$`.

Sometimes we have the env in the log file name and I can just drop this right in as so:
`source=logs/my-app/myapp-$global_env$.log`

However, some of our legacy apps are not using that standard, and I'll need to map the global_env to a server_name and query it as: `host=$server_name$`

I'm having a hard time getting this to work and would like a little guidance through a few questions:

1. Is there a way to set the server_name globally when the environment dropdown changes? (e.g. the user selects "Prod" from the dropdown, setting the global var `$global_env$ = "prod"` AND a hidden global var of `$server_name$="srv01"`)  It doesn't seem like this is possible outright, but maybe there's a trick somewhere I'm missing?
2. If #1 is not possible, then I'd like to use something like a `case` or `if` to set this in the query, like so:
   `host=case($global_env$=="prod", "mysrv1", $global_env$="uat", "mysrvuat1", $global_env$=="int", "mysrvint1") AND ...`
   or
   `host=if($global_env$=="prod", "mysrv1", "mysrv$global_env$1")`

I've tried #2 a few different ways, but it usually just drops the environment name into the query without seeming to run the `case` or `if` statement.

I've tried using an eval like so `eval server_name=case(...) | search host=$server_name$ AND ...` but that just leaves dashboard widget stuck "Waiting for input..."

Any suggestions how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set tokens when a dropdown changes.  Put a `<set>` element within a `<change>` element to set as many tokens as you like.

```
<input type="dropdown" token="global_env">
  <choice value="prod">Prod</choice>
  ...
  <change>
    <condition label="Prod">
      <set token="server_name">srv01</set>
    </condition>
  </change>
</input>
```

Comment: Is there an analogue to this in the json-based Dashboard Studio editor? I'm looking around and failing to come up with one..

Comment: Dashboard Studio is a different beast that is still in development so not all Simple XML features have DS equivalents (yet). (Next time, please mention you're using DS.)

Comment: Added "Dashboard Studio" to the question. Thank you for your response!